# Changing the time zone and language

Tags: python, locale, localtime

I need some advice to change the time zone and alphabets:

```
Localtime=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

How to change this one in persian text and Iran’s local time?

Comment: From the doc:  "*Locale information is not used by asctime()*" so use `localtime()` instead and covert the `struct time` yourself - this is assuming that you have set the locale correctly - https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: You can use [`locale.nl_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.nl_langinfo) to convert `localtime` to your locale (along with `time.strftime()`).

Comment: You can use the package [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)  with `strftime` to change the format and `timedelta` to add/remove hours depending on the local time.